# Android Service Doesn't Stop

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-service-binding

I made a app that starts a service in the Mainactivity. The Activity then binds to the service. In the onDestroy method of the activity I unbind from the service and then call stopService(). When I run my app on Android 4.4 Nexus 5 everything is fine. The service is stopped when I close the app. When I run it on a Nexus 5 running Android 6.0 the service isn't destroyed. Why is this happening?

Comment: onUnbind(Intent intent) must return true and start before onDestroy()